# Accessing Data in a relationship from another entity in a powerapp component

Tags: javascript, typescript, components, dynamics-crm

I have a one-to-many relationship between the accounts entity and a custom entity called clients where an account can have many clients. I am developing a powerapp component that I want to display details about the latest added client on the accounts main form.

What I’d like to know is how I would identify the account being viewed (as in get the relationship identifier) and retrieve the related data from the client entity.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your relationship it is 1(Account)-->N (clients).
so based on this, on your every client record you will have a lookup filed (relationship) filed which will look up to Account Record.

below is an example for Javascript but this will give you understanding of data structure and relationship
Example: get all contacts for a Parent Account

```
// NOTE: retrieveMultipleRecords is available in offline mode, if you need this functionality change the call to Xrm.WebApi.offline.retrieveMultipleRecords
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/offline
Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveMultipleRecords("contact", "?$select=contactid,_parentcustomerid_value,fullname&$filter=_parentcustomerid_value eq 7b649f5c-c986-e411-a2ea-00505693000c").then(
    function success(results) {
        console.log(results);
        for (var i = 0; i < results.entities.length; i++) {
            var result = results.entities[i];
            // Columns
            var contactid = result["contactid"]; // Guid
            var parentcustomerid = result["_parentcustomerid_value"]; // Customer
            var parentcustomerid_formatted = result["_parentcustomerid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
            var parentcustomerid_lookuplogicalname = result["_parentcustomerid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"];
            var fullname = result["fullname"]; // Text
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
);
```